# XSD Validation: Use attribute in same file as definition?

Tags: xsd, attributes

I have a large .xsd file structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns="foo:bar:baz" xmlns:quux="foo:bar:baz"
            quux:attr1="A" quux:attr2="5">
    <xsd:attribute name="attr1" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="attr2" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            <xhtml:h1 quux:attr1="A" quux:attr2="5">
                Documentation here
            </xhtml:h1>
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType name=...  />
</xsd:schema>
```

I get the error: "The foo:bar:baz:attr1" attribute is not declared.

Why is it not finding the attribute? It's right there. How can I make these attributes available to the documentation's header?

Future edit: the above schema got the green light from actual XML Validators. Guess there was just something Visual Studio was reading incorrectly.

Comment: What tool is giving that error?  Can you provide a [mcve]?  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes The error shows up when I edit in Visual Studio. The error message that I get when I run it through Xerxes-C (within a proprietary program) is vague, but I have reason to believe it comes down to this file. What more would you need to see to consider it complete and verifiable? This breaks on my machine.

Comment: The ***smallest, complete*** XSD for which the error occurs, and specific instructions that someone else can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The XSD you show can be imported or included into another XSD that includes an element declaration, but alone it cannot be used to validate an XML file because it does not declare even a single element.

Comment: I'm not trying to validate an XML file, I'm trying to use an attribute in the documentation without getting an error.